# What parameter permutations will change the behavior of rsync?

Tags: rsync

I'm creating a test for an rsync like application which verifies that the behavior of the application is consistent with that of rysnc. I am primarily concerned with how different permutations of input parameters change the behavior of rsync. So far I have identified the following parameter permutations:

presence or absence of a trailing '/' after source

presence or absence of a trailing '/' after destination

presence or absence of the target destination directory (including a third option where the destination listed is a file)

absence of the destination's parent directory

inclusion or exclusion of recursion

Can anyone offer suggestions as to other parameter permutations that may change the behavior of rsync?

Comment: Are you looking for this?  http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one:

Whether the destination permissions are accessible.  For example, destination is a directory that is readable, but not writable, or not executable.